# Encode array of images exception

Tags: objective-c, encode

i try to encode an array with UIImages.

Then i call "save" function

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedUserData"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: self toFile:filePath];
```

i get exception for line
 `[encoder encodeObject:recipePhotoList forKey:@"recipePhotoList"];` //array with images

```
 -[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b1380
2012-03-23 11:59:43.694 fishmarket[261:1a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b1380'
```

On 5+ iOS its working perfectly, on 4.3 i have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some alternative to encode/decode UIIMage for iOS < 5.0

```
+ (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image withName:(NSString*)imageName
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:imageName]];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}

+ (UIImage*)loadImageNamed:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:imageName]];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
```

hope its help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `UIImage` didn't support `NSCoding` until iOS 5. Check the [iOS 5.0 API diff.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011042)

Comment: i guess so.. But that shell i do to encode it? encode to bytes array?